# Start from scratch LDAP server CentOS

Tags: centos, configuration, openldap

I am trying to set up a LDAP authentication server but I have messed too much with it, and I would like to start from scratch its configuration without reinstalling the OS because I have other stuff inside it (my fault for not doing it in a test machine).
I am running CentOS 7.

Edit (I would try to explain better why I want to restart): I deleted my top domain and I do not know how to add it again.

Comment: Reinstalling the OS takes what, 15 minutes? Will probably be a lot faster than reverting all the changes you have made. There is no such thing like a "factory reset".

Comment: Problem is that I have installed a fog server and would prefer not to reinstall it

Answer (score 0):

You can populate your openldap database with [slapadd](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/dbtools.html) (section 10.2.1. The slapadd program)

```
stop openldap 
slapadd
start openldap
```

If You're running slapadd as root check backend files permissions and chown to openldap user before starting openldap again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, when I do the slapadd command I receive "The first database does not allow slapadd; using the first available one (2)" and it seems to be frozen, is this the expected result (waiting)?

Comment: The warning is probably OK. The process isn't frozen, It expects LDIF file in the stdin or in the file passed as option to slapadd `-l file.ldif`. See https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/dbtools.html example LDIF here at the bottom of section "10.1. Creating a database over LDAP"

Comment: Thank you again for your quick answer, I have checked permissions and they seems okay, but when I try to start slapd I get an error about read/write permission in __db.002 and __db.003

Comment: And the ownership of db files? Do they belong to correct user?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I won't be able to do anything until the day after tomorrow, but yes, I checked and I gave the ownership to the ldap user. Sorry for all the hassle and thank you.

Comment: Okay, I did `yum reinstall openldap` and now it starts correctly, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

- [RTFM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM) - [OpenLDAP 2.4 Admin docs](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/guide.html#A%20Quick-Start%20Guide)
- Also install the `docs` subpkg for `openldap` for the example configuration.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that I should I've tried reinstalling, if anyones want to know I just did:

`yum reinstall openldap openldap-servers openldap-devel`